# htaccess rewrite rule removing get parameter

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this kind of url:

```
http://www.example.com/activities?_activities=surf
```

What I'm trying to do is to get this other kind of url:

```
http://www.example.com/activities/surf
```

So what I need is just to remove ?_activities from url.

I tried to write some rewrite rule in htaccess but with no success.

Here what I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _activities=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /activities/%1/? [R=301,L]
```

What I'm wrong?

Comment: @Mandy8055 unfortunatly no.. I need an htaccess rule.. I tried my rule here https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and it seems to work, but when I put it in the .htaccess nothing happen visiting http://www.example.com/activities?_activities=surf (it should make a redirect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the QSD (query string discard) flag removes the query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _activities=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) $1/%1 [R=301,L,QSD]
```

Applied to
`http://www.example.com/activities?_activities=surf`
the output will be 
`http://www.example.com/activities/surf`

Note to the various flags:

- NC: non-case-sensitive
- R: redirect, 301 means permanent redirect
- L: last rule, if the rule matches, no further rules are being processed.

Comment: Formally it works, but the redirect isn't performed.. I'm running wordpress with mod_rewrite on, so I don't understand why redirect doesn't work.. Any idea? :)

Comment: @Adriano show where in the context of the existing WP .htaccess file you placed this then.

Comment: @CBroe sure.. I placed rule just after #End Wordpress comment.. below .htaccess:
`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# Rewrite Activities
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _activities=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) $1%1 [R=301,L,QSD]`

Comment: You need to do this the other way around. Anything that does not physically exist, gets rewritten to the index.php, and that is flagged as the `L` last rule to be performed. Rule of thumb: More specific rewrites first, less specific ones later.